# jquery datetimepicker trentrichardson - simple but I don't understand

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here and why this simple datetimepicker will not come up?  I am a jquery newb and getting frustrated already :)

```
<head runat="server">
<title>IT Support Tools - Log Viewer</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("hello");
            $('#<%=txtStartDate.ClientID%>').datetimepicker();
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the source code look like after the ASP gets evaluated:

Comment: not much to go on there Dan! Have you included the plugin, do you get any errors, do the resources load correctly, is $('#<%=txtStartDate.ClientID%>').length == 1 when you try to initialise the plugin.....

Comment: @redsquare I downloaded the .js file here http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/.  Then saved it and referenced it along with the jquery library.  I'm new to this stack overflow site.  I'm not sure you can see all the code I actually pasted originally because I only see 2 lines now.  Let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to link jQueryUI, that plugin is based on it. The site you grabbed it from mentions that. Put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Between the two `<script>` tags you already have.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew it was something simple and obvious.  I just couldn't tell from the trentrichardson site since he mentioned it but didn't have any full example code.  I just installed this through nuget http://nuget.org/List/Packages/jQuery.UI.Combined

Comment: I don't know nuget, but looks interesting!